# How to reference a File In Use dialog from a Word.Application object

Tags: python-2.7, com, ms-word, dialog

How can one obtain a reference to a dialog that results from the following steps? I ran Microsoft Word 2013 programmatically.

1. Intentionally try to open a locked .docx file by passing the entire file path to the Open method of the Documents member of the Word.Application object.
2. Because the file is locked, a dialog entitled File In Use appears and contains the text: filename.extension is locked for editing by 'username'. Do you want to:

   - Open a Read Only copy
   - Create a local copy and merge your changes later
   - Receive notification when the original copy is available

   followed by the buttons OK and Cancel.

I'm trying to obtain a reference to this recently-created (but not by my code) object primarily to confirm that it was created and secondarily to perhaps manipulate it from a program rather than user input. However, I can't reach it from either the Word.Application or Documents objects.

The following is the Python code (v2.7.11 on win32) I used.

```
import win32com.client
wordapp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
wordapp.Documents.Open("\\\\10.1.3.70\\subroot\\test.docx")
<COMObject Open>
wordapp.Documents.Open("\\\\10.1.3.70\\subroot2\\test.docx")
```

subroot and subroot2 are shares that access the same dir.

Comment: And what is the code?

Comment: Why do you need it as a Word object? Can't you substantiate the file's been created if it's been written to disk? There's no way you can work with a file that's open and being edited somewhere else. You could use GetObject (GetActiveObject is you're programming in .NET) to work with the actual, opened file - although here, as well, you may be in conflict with the user.

Comment: @Rahul, I added my code to my question.

Comment: @CindyMeister, I need a reference to the File In Use object to confirm that a conflict occurs if a locked file is opened for editing. I don't plan to actually edit the file.

Comment: Windows API is the only thing that can get that dialog / message, it's not exposed in the Word object model. Much better to check for the presence of the file and the file lock, rather than trying to open a locked file. You could also try setting the Documents.Open parameter to force the document to open Read-Only, which should open it without the dialog showing - but I don't know if that actually helps you.